# Similarity function in Postgres with pg_trgm

Tags: sql, postgresql, fuzzy-search

I'm trying to use the similarity function in Postgres to do some fuzzy text matching, however whenever I try to use it I get the error:

```
function similarity(character varying, unknown) does not exist
```

If I add explicit casts to text I get the error:

```
function similarity(text, text) does not exist
```

My query is:

```
SELECT (similarity("table"."field"::text, %s::text)) AS "similarity", "table".* FROM "table" WHERE similarity > .5 ORDER BY "similarity" DESC LIMIT 10
```

Do I need to do something to initalize pg_trgm?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to install pg_trgm. In debian, source this sql: `/usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/pg_trgm.sql`. From the command line:

```
psql -f /usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/pg_trgm.sql
```

Or inside a psql shell:

```
\i /usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/pg_trgm.sql
```

The script defaults to installing in the public schema, edit the search path at the top if you want to install it somewhere else (so that uninstalling/upgrading can be done simply by dropping the schema).

Comment: Possibly really dumb question, but how does one do that?

Answer (score 70):

With postgresql 9.1:

after installing (on ubuntu) `sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib` as tomaszbak answered.

you just have to execute the sql command:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
```

Comment: It may be worth to remember that depending on database search_path extension could be installed in different schema than public.

Comment: note: since you have to be superuser, go to the commandline and select your database **psql --username postgres --dbname database** and run the command there. Just in default database won't work for your production app

Answer (score 8):

On ubuntu you need to run

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib
```

to get /usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/pg_trgm.sql

Comment: For postgres 8.4. contrib run `sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib-8.4`

Answer (score 5):

If you have the `pg_trgm` extension installed *not* in the `public` schema you must explicitly specify the schema when using the `similarity` function like this

```
select schema.similarity(foo,bar) from schema.baz
```

Comment: How do I find out which schema has it installed?

Answer (score 2):

For Postgres **8.4** do following:

As sudo user run:

`sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib-8.4`

Switch to postgres user:

`sudo su - postgres`

Run:

`psql -U DB_USER -d DB_NAME -f /usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/pg_trgm.sql`

Restart postgres

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue in the context of running the Django Test Runner against a function that uses the Django 1.11 ORM for trigram similarity on Postgres 9.4.

I had to do a few things to get it working:

1) OP is correct that this required enabling the `pg_trgm` extension. However, in postgres9.4 this is enabled on a per-database basis. Since Django deletes and recreates the test database with each run, the new test database didn't have the extension installed. To fix this, I initialized the `pg_trgm` extension within the default newly-created database template in postgres. The command to do this is `psql -d template1 -c 'CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;'` run as the `postgres` user.

2) Postgres had to be restarted

3) The Django test runner wasn't recognizing this, so I had to upgrade from Django 1.11.12 to 1.11.18 (presumably this is also fixed in newer versions of Django)

Answer (score 0):

in case others are struggling too: assuming that the db is called “ttrss” I switched to the command line of postgresql:

```
sudo -u postgres psql --dbname=ttrss
```

then install the extension there:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
```