# How to use pg_trgm after postgresql installation from source

Tags: postgresql, installation

After succesfully installing postgresql 9.2.2 from source (on OpenSUSE 11.4, which does not have this version in the repositories),  I am trying to restore a database that makes use of the pg_trgm extension.  This results in errors because pg_trgm is not found.

From this StackOverflow question: [Similarity function in Postgres with pg_trgm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254999/similarity-function-in-postgres-with-pg-trgm),  I gather that pg_trgm should be in /usr/share/postgresql//contrib,  but there is no contrib folder anywhere in my /usr tree.

Also,  I cannot seem to find a clear explanation of how the postgres extension mechanism works,  or how to manually install an extension.

There is a contrib folder in the postgresql source tree,  but I am not sure how to use this.  Should I manually copy this somewhere to /usr tree? Can anyone point me to (or give) an explanation of how to install an extension like pg_trgm in postgresql?

Answer (score 17):

Assuming you have configured postgresql with `./configure`, it has used the default prefix `/usr/local/pgsql`, so that everything gets installed below that directory.

The answer you link to relates to Debian, which uses a different layout that conforms to the Debian policy, but in your case `/usr/share...` is irrelevant. Anyway it's not really necessary to know that in order to install stuff from contrib, since there is no need to copy anything manually.

To install the `pg_trgm` extension from source, there are two steps:

1) build and install it from your postgresql source tree:

```
$ cd /path/to/src/postgresql-9.2.2/contrib/pg_trgm
$ make
$ sudo make install # or su -c 'make install' if you don't use sudo
```

2) activate it with `psql` in your database:

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql -d database -c "create extension pg_trgm;"
```

To have it activated by default on any database created in the future, apply this command to the `template1` database.

Answer (score 2):

I've use Postgresql in the Centos 7 and the package with the pg_trgm allowed to install:

> $yum install postgresql-contrib