# Django Postgres pg_trgm module with djorm-ext-pgfulltext for full text searches

Tags: python, django, postgresql

With Django 1.6 and postgres and the module `djorm-ext-pgfulltext`, I am trying to perform full text searches that use greedy matching(ie: app would match apple) instead of exact word matching.

I see that postgres has pg_trgm module(http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/pgtrgm.html) for this(match 3 consecutive characters of search word). However, I am pretty stumped on how I would integrate/use this in `djorm-ext-pgfulltext`. I know that `SearchManager()` does take a config arguement, but I am not sure how I would use pg_trgm in it. I read over making my own configuration file [enter link description here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/textsearch-configuration.html) but I don't see a way to integrate `pg_trgm` in there ether.

```
objects = SearchManager(
    fields = ('name', 'description'),
    config = 'pg_catalog.english', # this is default
    search_field = 'search_index', # this is default
    auto_update_search_field = True
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Found this post which solved all my problems. All I needed to do was go into the database and run `CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;`

[Similarity function in Postgres with pg_trgm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254999/similarity-function-in-postgres-with-pg-trgm)