# HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. TrigramSimilarity Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, postgresql

I am trying full text search using `TrigramSimilarity`. I have activated  `pg_trgm` extension in PostgreSQL. and added `django.contrib.postgres` in my installed apps. But when I am trying query

```
blog.objects.annotate(similarity=TrigramSimilarity('name', 'abc'),).filter(similarity__gt=0.3).order_by('-similarity')
```

But its giving me an error

> psycopg2.ProgrammingError: function similarity(character varying, unknown) does not exist
>       LINE 1: ...others_2", "blog_mod", SIMILARITY...
>                                                  ^
>       HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Why this error is happening. Please help me.

Comment: Does the `blog` model class have a `name` field?

Comment: yes it has name field

Comment: Then it seems that the pg_trgm extension has not been installed in the database. What did you do to enable it? Have you checked that it's successfully installed?

Comment: I get into my db using "sudo -u postgres psql" and used this command "CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;"

Comment: The error message is consistent with `pg_trgm` not being created. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254999/similarity-function-in-postgres-with-pg-trgm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error indicates that the extension has not been installed. I don't know exactly why that could be. Possibly you did not install the extension in the database you use for django?

It is possible to perform raw sql queries from your django code. This will ensure that you target the correct database / schema.

```
from django.db import connection
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute('CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm')
```

You can also use Django's custom `TrigramExtension` migration. The create extension query is the same. But the migration is a good idea if you run integration tests on a test database that also needs pg_trgm to be enabled.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/operations/#database-migration-operations

Comment: yeah it worked. I installed pg_trgm in my default database insted of the databse which django uses. Thankyou very much

Comment: This did not solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

It's because (I don't know why?) TrigramSimilarity wont work on search_query. instead it will work with strings. or neither with SearchVectorField instead use regular fields.

Answer (score 1):

If the pg_trgm extension was created in the public schema you can get the error in another schema. This works for me:

```
select public.similarity('foo','bar');
```

whereas if I try Szymon's solution Postgres tells me the extension already exists. I haven't found documentation on this.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue. This would happen if you did not include the schema where `TrigramSimilarity()` will be used in the search path before installing this extension.

Try

```sql
SET search_path TO my_schema
```

Then

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm;
```

Answer (score -1):

My guess is you probably have not connected to the right DB.

In Ubuntu. Try...

```
$ sudo su postgres

$ psql <db_name>
   <db_name> = Name of DB being used by the Django project.
   e.g psql badass_db

$ CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
```