# How do I create or move the pg_trgm--1.3.sql into the correct path to clear this SIMILARITY error?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, ubuntu-18.04

[image]

After installing PostgreSQL I keep getting an error.

"***LINE 1: ...T COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT "blog_post"."id" AS Col1, SIMILARITY...***"

HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

sudo apt install postgresql-contrib
psql# CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
sudo service postgresql restart

(venv) dev-py@devpy-VirtualBox:~/Dev/mysite/mysite$ python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
July 12, 2019 - 20:31:19
Django version 2.2.3, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[12/Jul/2019 20:31:32] "GET /blog/search/ HTTP/1.1" 200 995
Internal Server Error: /blog/search/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dev-py/Dev/mysite/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction: function similarity(character varying, unknown) does not exist

"***LINE 1: ...T COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT "blog_post"."id" AS Col1, SIMILARITY...***"

HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Any help would be appreciated. It took me 3 days of troubleshooting this before I asked for help but I am sure someone knows the answer and it's simple. If you need any more info please just lmk.

Comment: 1) `UndefinedFunction: function similarity(character varying, unknown) does not exist` - look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2255053/3350428. 2) Is `COUNT()` instead of `COUNT(*)` a typo?

Comment: Yes yes a typo. I have located the pg_trgm.control file at /usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/pg_trgm.control. But is it supposed to be in /usr/share/postgresql/10/contrib/pg_trgm ? @AndreiOdegov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use trigrams in PostgreSQL, you will need to install the pg_trgm extension first. Execute the following command from the shell to connect to the DB.

```
psql blog
```

Then, execute the following command to install the pg_trgm extension:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
```

Done.

Comment: It's because (I don't know why?) TrigramSimilarity wont work on search_query.
instead it will work with strings. or neither with SearchVectorField instead use regular fields.