# Error while configuring postgressql for django

Tags: django, postgresql

I have implemented full text search in my django app using postgresql. But, when I press the search button, I get an error:

```
ProgrammingError at /blog/search/
function similarity(character varying, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT SIMILARITY("blog_post"."title",...
                                     ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I don't know where the error is, so if you need any files, I will edit this question.
Please help me

Comment: this may help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254999/similarity-function-in-postgres-with-pg-trgm

Comment: this does not use django. I am using django for my app

Comment: You should add more debugging details to the question!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you forgot to install the **[`pg_trgm`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/pgtrgm.html)** extension.  To install it using django, create a file called `pg_trgm.py` inside of your app's **`migrations`** directory:

```
from django.db import migrations

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('myapp', <last migration filename here>),
    ]
    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL('CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm'),
    ]
```

Remember to replace `<last migration filename here>` with the filename of your most recent migration.

Comment: This works perfectly. but could you tell me a solution that is permanant. I have to repeat this step in every django project, which I don't want to. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Are you working with 'Django by Example' book?
Did you put the real DB at 'psql blog' command ?
I get the same error, so I tryed 'psql blogDB'... the real name that I gave.
That work fine!